# ASP.NET HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a problem running my `asp.net` pages on `IIS 7`. When I try to run it on my local host it displays an error page:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
```

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

I've tried most of the stuff I've found on the web like changing the file sharing`(\ASPNET, \IIS_IUSRS),` setting permission of section `name="handlers"` and `section name="modules"` to `"Allow"` (it crash my `IIS` and I get an error `"503 - Service unavailable"`). I also tried reinstalling the whole thing(`IIS` first then `ASP.NET`) and using the `aspnet_regiis -i` and still no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this by adding the  entry for each of the subsequent name entries. For instance:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="Elmah"/>
  <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have invalid configuration or your iis is not good installed.

may be this will help: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;929772

or: http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7.aspx